# Rails always build and install node-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg

When I run `rails new SomeApp` or clone some rails apps and then run `yarn install` it always installs stuff that I already have, the most annoying one is `node-sass` which takes > 5 minutes alone for the compilation on single core.

In case of `bundle install` though, it's instantaneous, it uses the gems I have on my system.

Is there a way to install `node-sass` once and use that in all new rails apps?